# WordPress: image_send_to_editor retrieve selected image width and height

Tags: image, wordpress, replace, editor

I modified the 'image_send_to_editor' code in functions.php for image caption and image  added by the editor. Specifically the images selected from media gallery.

At the moment, I can't access the Width and Height of the selected image. What variable are missing to make this possible? Ideally the image tag would look like the line below.

```
<img src='$url' alt='$title' class='size-$size' width='IMAGE-WIDTH' height='IMAGE-HEIGHT'>

// image and caption replace 
function html5_insert_image($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size) {
    $html5 = "<figure id='post-$id media-$id' class='figure align$align'>";
    $html5 .= "<img src='$url' alt='$title' class='size-$size'>";
    if ($caption) {
        $html5 .= "<figcaption>$caption</figcaption>";
    }
    $html5 .= "</figure>";
    return $html5;
}
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'html5_insert_image', 10, 9 );
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried this and similar snippets from the web for a project, and there's two things I've noted so far that could cause issues.
First, if you try to edit the caption of an existing image, it causes a mess.
Secondly, removing the image only removes the img tag. It leaves the figure tags in the editor, invisible to a non-HTML using user.
If anyone has a workaround for these issues, I'd love to hear them, as WP is not my normal wheelhouse.

Comment: @Charasan did you try the code below? Were you able to resolve your issue?

Comment: I hadn't revisited this in a while. Will altering the <figure> tag address the issues I had? I'll try the change and see how it works out.

Comment: Sorry, it does seem cleaner. At least the caption portion, but it ignores the figcaption in favor of default WP behavior, and the <figure> tags still remains when removing the image via the WP tools. Sorry, I hadn't revisited this problem in a while, forgot it was here.

Comment: I'm not sure, I understand your problem. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue using 'get_image_tag' function. This returns both the image width and height. Now I can pick the different image sizes from media library.

```
function html5_insert_image($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size) {

    /**** START - ADD THIS LINE TO RETRIEVE THE WIDTH & HEIGHT ****/
    $html = get_image_tag($id, '', $title, $align, $size);    
    /**** END ****/

    $html5 = "<figure id='post-$id media-$id' class='figure align$align'>";
    $html5 .= $html;
    if ($caption) {
        $html5 .= "<figcaption>$caption</figcaption>";
    }
    $html5 .= "</figure>";
    return $html5;
}
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'html5_insert_image', 10, 9 );
```

Comment: i tested this code work without any problem but it is not work with these images that have the captions